# How to make my background image cover the entire web page. When i shorten the height the background image stops at certain length

Tags: css

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(58,58,158,0.8), 
  rgba(136,136,206,0.7)), 
  url("pic.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

---

So the issue im having is when i shorten the height the background image stops at some point and the flex container keeps running on into white space. The width scales properly of the picture, just the height is not right.

Comment: min-height instead of height

Comment: Alternatively you could use `background-attachment: fixed;` if you want the image to stay in place when scrolling, unless the image is optimized to be very very long it will not look great on a larger page

Comment: Great I will try both of these solutions.

Comment: So the min-height worked great. does what it should do now.